# Passing Collection ID to generate Forms in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I've a collection "Country" which displays a list of countries and their info. A book option leads a user to the "Activity" form which has dropdown fields like To,From. How do I pass the "Country" ID so that the form fields in "Activity" belong to the "Country" whose Book button the user has clicked. I think I should use a reactive var to store the country id and then perform operations to change the form fields accordingly. I'm fairly new to this and a heads up to the approach would be deeply appreciated.

The submit code for activity collection is :

```
    Template.activitySubmit.onRendered(function () {
    if (Session.get("submit-bypass") === true) {
        Session.set("submit-bypass", false);
        window.history.back();
    }

    $("#activity-goal").material_select();
});

Template.activitySubmit.events({
    "submit form": function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var title = $(e.target).find("#activity-title").val()
        if (title.length === 0) {
            throwError("You must have a title.");
            $("activity-title").focus();
            return;
        }

        var activty = {
            title: title,
            goal: parseInt($(e.target).find("#activity-goal").val())
        };

        Meteor.call("activityInsert", activty, function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                throwError(error.reason);
                return;
            }

            Session.set("submit-bypass", true);
            Router.go("activityPage", { _id: result._id });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use reactive var to store some data within the same template. 
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg

Comment: @alexndm Hey, I'm thinking of the same but I can't quite know the implementation. I was looking forward to a heads up into this! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should use reactive var package

1. Add the package to your project, in terminal `meteor add reactive-var`
2. Open your JS file for the template, like `activitySubmit.js`
3. Declare reactive var like so

   `Template.activitySubmit.onRendered(function () {
    this.selectedCountry = new ReactiveVar(null);
   });`
4. Then update the reactive var as needed and use it

`

```
Template.activitySubmit.events({
      'change #country': function(e){
         var country = $(e.target).val()
         var instance = Template.instance();
         instance.selectedCountry.set(country);
      },


  'submit form': function (e) {
     ....
      var instance = Template.instance();
      var country = instance.selectedCountry.get(country);
     ....
  }

});`
```

5. If you'd like to pass the data around across mulitple files (globally), you can simply use Session. `Session.set('myId', id)` and `Session.get('myId')`

Comment: Thanks again man, but the way I planned it was to store the ID of the Country on click of the "book" button and in the Acitivity.js use the ID to change the values. How I can use reactive var to capture the ID of an object in a  list using a simple <a class="button> tag button.

Comment: If it's used across multiple files, maybe you should use Session ?

Comment: I'm going for what would be easier for me as I'm quite new to meteor. Once I get the ID I could do the rest in JS but the meteor part is screwing me up. This is how the list page is http://postimg.org/image/7xycmagcz/ with each of the items generated using a mongodb collection. I need a way to differentiate which "book" button did the user click. Thanks for taking you time though, I'm sorry I tried it myself reading high and low but I couldn't implement this.

Comment: The easiest would be to use Session. On click event (or any event)m just do `Session.set('myId', id)`, where id is the value you'd lilke to store and then retrieve it anywhere in the app with `Session.get('myId')`

Comment: Thanks Alex, I owe you one for this :)! I'll try this right now.